# Java Keyfactory can't generate ECPublicKey using nimbus

Tags: java, jwt, openid, elliptic-curve

I'm trying to validate a JWT token of EC type algorithm received from PingAccess using nimbusds library. It doesn't work in all environments.  But they all have the same version of Java.  Some environment couldn't generate the ECPublickey object with the key specs, so it can't find a matched key from the remote keyset.  Does anyone have the similar experience with JWT token with EC algorithm?  How can I know if the EC algorithm exists in the environment? From the doc here,https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/security/KeyFactory.html,

> Every implementation of the Java platform is required to support the
>   following standard KeyFactory algorithms:
>
> DiffieHellman DSA RSA

It doesn't mention EC algorithms, but it's listed here :https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyFactory

In nimbusds ECKey Class, the trace stopped at this line:

```
ECPublicKey ecPublicKey = (ECPublicKey)keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
```

Key factory is:

```
 keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not being given a stacktrace, it's a bit of guess work on my side. However, given that it works on some environments, it seems likely to me that some environments (those that work) have the Unlimited key strength policy files enabled, and others (those that don't work) have not.

Likely the public key that needs to be generated is larger than what is available under standard policy.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem is the provider list in `java.security file`. Without given a specific, provider for the algorithm, it will use the default provider in the list provided in java.security. In a production environment, that file is missing. Hard to figure it out because there is no exception thrown out or an error. In short, `java.security` file is missing and it couldn't find the algorithm provider.